# javax.naming.NameNotFoundException in tomee plume ejb 3.0 and webservices

Tags: jax-ws, ejb-3.0, apache-tomee

I have one webservice project and one EJB 3.0 project deployed in Tomee plume in same EAR.
From webservice class i'm calling EJB bean class using remote interface.
i have used multiple InitialContextFactory object, but nothing seems to work . Each time i'm getting

**javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name "TestRemote" not found**

while deployment, this log is coming in server.

**08-Sep-2017 16:23:09.587 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.JndiBuilder.bind Jndi(name=TestRemote) --> Ejb(deployment-id=Test)**

Here is the code from my webservice class

```
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("java.naming.factory.initial", "org.apache.openejb.core.OpenEJBInitialContextFactory");
        properties.put("java.naming.provider.url", "http://localhost:8081");
        InitialContext ic = new InitialContext(properties);
        TestRemote PSBR = (TestRemote) ic.lookup("TestRemote");
```

Apart from OpenEJBInitialContextFactory, i have tried **org.apache.openejb.core.LocalInitialContextFactory** and **RemoteInitialContextFactory** but getting the same error each time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i used this code and did change in system.properties and it got solved.

```
    properties.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.apache.openejb.client.RemoteInitialContextFactory");
properties.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "http://127.0.0.1:8081/tomee/ejb");
```

and change in system.properties.

```
# allowed packages to be deserialized, by security we denied all by default, tune tomee.serialization.class.whitelist packages to change it
tomee.remote.support = true
tomee.serialization.class.whitelist = *
tomee.serialization.class.blacklist = -
```